# How to copy the value of a dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

i declare a dynamic array `int *idArray;` and i want to copy the value to a `tempArray`, then i will change the order of `tempArray`, but i don't want to change the order `idArray`, how can i write it? I have tried to implement it, but when the order of `tempArray` be changed, the order of `idArray` also change.

```
int *idArray = new int[size]; 
int *tempArray = idArray;
int m, n;
for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    m = rand() % size;
    n = tempArray[m];
    tempArray[m] = tempArray[k];
    tempArray[k] = n; 
}
```

Comment: if you are talking about c++, why not std::array or at least std::vector? do you really need raw pointers? It is not a temporary array, it is a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> idArray(size); 
std::vector<int> tempArray = idArray;
```

Problemo solvo.

Also, you can use `std::random_shuffle`- you don't have to shuffle the vector yourself.

Comment: You forgot the `random_shuffle` :)

Comment: @msandiford: Nah, the rest of his code can stay as it is or change, or whatever. The *problem* is the pointer aliasing, which I have solved.

Comment: This is the perfect use-case for a vector, forget raw dynamic arrays.

Comment: What language is that last sentence written in?

Comment: @Soohjun: It's a Dead language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `std::vector<>` for array. `std::vector<>` will handle copying and other memory management for you. Plus it remembers array's size. (`new[]` doesn't.)

Otherwise you need to do following:

```
int *idArray = new int[size]; 
int idArray_size = size; // note this. you need to save array's size somewhere.
.......
int *tempArray = new int[idArray_size];

/* copy */
for(int i = 0; i < idArray_size; i++)
    tempArray[i] = idArray[i];

int m, n;
for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    m = rand() % size;
    n = tempArray[m];
    tempArray[m] = tempArray[k];
    tempArray[k] = n; 
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Dubious. If I were you, I would just show the code using `std::vector`. As it is, it's border-line downvotable. Right now, I decided not to, though.

Comment: You can do the copying semantically more clearly (and possibly also more efficiently) by using `std::copy(idArray, idArray+size, tempArray);`

Comment: @DeadMG, it depends. I answered his question (not wanting to use `std::array` can be perfectly valid scenario), plus suggested better solution. I don't want to force him to use 'c++' way, when others are possible.

Comment: @Yossarian: He's coding in C++. What other way is there to code in C++ except the C++ way?

Answer (score 0):

Because your temp array is Pointed On your Id array

> int *tempArray = idArray;

So in stead of this you Declare Yout `*tempArray` and manualy copy value from Idarray to temp Array

Comment: Actually, merely _declaring_ your own array isn't enough to also use it. You will have to _[define](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719)_ it.

Answer (score -3):

This is the actual memory you are allocating and idArray points to it:

```
int *idArray = new int[size];
```

And this is just a pointer to that same memory address:

```
int *tempArray = idArray;
```

You should declare tempArray same as idArray and then just copy the content to it:

```
int *idArray = new int[size];
int *tempArray = new int[size];
memcpy(tempArray,idArray,size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Thanks for your help! Since i can't reply on your post, i reply here:)